# How to insert variables in an url?

Tags: ruby

I have this code for send a request to an url, and I wanted to place on the url two variables :

```
talksList = open('http://yolo.com/?action=cp_list&id=#{variable1}&key=#{variable2}')
```

But when I insert my variables like this, it doesn't work. Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As @YuHao said, you're trying to interpolate a variable into a non-interpreted string. But you have a bigger long-term problem.

Don't try to inject unencoded variables into a URL. While it will work, you run the risk of generating nonsensical URLs, which a browser would accept, but code won't. Instead, use the appropriate tools to modify the URL, which will maintain appropriate encoding for you.

Here's an example using [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html):

```
require 'uri'

variable1 = 'foo'
variable2 = 'bar'

uri = URI.parse('http://yolo.com/?action=cp_list')
params = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query)
params << ['id', variable1]
params << ['key', variable2]
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)
uri.to_s # => "http://yolo.com/?action=cp_list&id=foo&key=bar"
```

You can do the same thing using the [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) gem, which is more full-featured:

```
require 'addressable/uri'

variable1 = 'foo'
variable2 = 'bar'

uri = Addressable::URI.parse('http://yolo.com/?action=cp_list')
params = uri.query_values
uri.query_values = params.merge('id' => variable1, 'key' => variable2)
uri.to_s # => "http://yolo.com/?action=cp_list&id=foo&key=bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using strings with single quotes. In single quoted strings, nothing is replaced except `\\` and `\'`.

Specifically, interpolation is only available in double quoted strings, try

```
talksList = open("http://yolo.com/?action=cp_list&id=#{variable1}&key=#{variable2}")
```

Comment: It is in progress, but there is another problem : I set my two variables correctly, but irb says that they are undefined. However, when I print them, the value is correct.

Comment: @Vinm That's a different problem, then ask a different question (after some research).